# React Typescript: Property 'match' is missing in type {}. (Trying to use properties in component initialisation)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Currently trying to get to grips with how to send properties when creating components.

I have a `LoginButton` component which I want to initialise with 'user' and 'avatarImg' props, like so:

```
interface LoginButtonState {
    userLoggedIn: boolean,
    user: Account,
    avatarImg: AccountImage,
}

export class LoginButton extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, LoginButtonState> {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            userLoggedIn: false,
            user: this.props.match.params["user"], // <---- Initialised here
            avatarImg: this.props.match.params["avatarImg"], // <-- and here
            modalOpen: false
        }

    }

//... functions, render(), etc,

}
```

Looking at various explanations online, I'm led to believe I should then create the `<LoginButton/>` component like so:

```
import { LoginButton } from './widgets/loginButton';
import { Account, AccountImage } from './DatabaseClasses';

export class Layout extends React.Component<LayoutProps, {}> {

    public render() {

    let testUser = new Account();
    let testImg = new AccountImage();

    return (
        <div id="outer-container">

            <LoginButton user={testUser} avatarImg={testImg}></LoginButton>

        </div>
    );}
}
```

But this gives me an error:

> Error TS2322  (TS) Type '{ user: Account; avatarImg: AccountImage; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly>'.
>     Property 'match' is missing in type '{ user: Account; avatarImg: AccountImage; }'.

I can see what the error is telling me, and I'm pretty sure the `TS` part means it's a Typescript thing, but I have idea how to go about fixing it..!

The only thing I've tried which made sense was to use the `any` type in the first part, forming `export class LoginButton extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<any>`, but the problem stays pretty much the same. The error becomes:

> Error TS2322  (TS) Type '{ user: Account; avatarImg: AccountImage; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly>'.
>     Property 'match' is missing in type '{ user: Account; avatarImg: AccountImage; }'.

Any pointers much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed thanks to this blog article: https://www.danielbischoff.com/blog/2018-02-26--ts-react-props/ **

I created a second interface called `LoginButtonProps` and used that in the declaration of the `LoginButton` class.

So it starts like this:

```
interface LoginButtonState {
    userLoggedIn: boolean,
    user: Account,
    avatarImg: AccountImage,
    modalOpen: boolean
}

interface LoginButtonProps {
    user: Account,
    avatarImg: AccountImage,
}

export class LoginButton extends React.Component<LoginButtonProps, LoginButtonState> {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userLoggedIn: false,
            user: this.props.user,
            avatarImg: this.props.avatarImg,
            modalOpen: false
        }

//...etc etc
```

Note how the state is set via `this.props.user`, and `this.props.avatarImg`. It knows what to look for because I've told it that the properties have been defined in that new interface.

Now I can set `<LoginButton user={testUser} avatarImg={testImg}></LoginButton>` and there are no errors, so it worked!

**(blog author is this guy - https://stackoverflow.com/users/2379376/daniel - I'm not sure how to tag other users in my answer, but cheers to him!)